# How can I map iostat device names to LVM /dev/mapper/XXX names?

Tags: linux, mount, lvm, iostat

mount shows mount devices like:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup01-LogVol00 on /var type ext3 (rw)
```

or

```
/dev/mapper/VolGrp_backups-backups on /mnt/backups type ext3 (rw)
```

but

iostat uses dm- notation. like `dm-0`, `dm-1` and so on.

Where can I find a way to know which is which?

Comment: Somehow, I thought there was a way to tell iostat to 'just do that', but there isn't one (that I can find). +1 for a great question that got an answer that helped me too.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`ls -l /dev/mapper/*`, the device minor number (field 6 of what `ls -l` outputs) corresponds to the number in `dm-\d+`.

Answer (score 13):

Depending on the version of iostat you have the `-N` option will do this for you:

> -N     Display the registered device mapper names for any device mapper
>   devices.  Useful for viewing LVM2 statistics.

Edit: versions >= 7.1.4 of systat (which includes iostat) have that option.

> 2007/04/29: Version 7.1.4 - Sebastien
>   Godard (sysstat  wanadoo.fr)
>           * Option -N added to iostat. This option enables the user to
>             query any device-mapper devices for their registered device
>             name [bugzilla #177540].

Comment: a more accurate answer for the question.

Answer (score 4):

you can try `lsblk` command which shows the Logical Volume used by respective dev-mapper.

```
# lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                          8:0    0    8G  0 disk
├─sda1                       8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2                       8:2    0  7.5G  0 part
  ├─vg_root-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0  5.6G  0 lvm  /
  └─vg_root-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
sdb                          8:16   0  200M  0 disk
sdc                          8:32   0  1.5G  0 disk
sdd                          8:48   0  512M  0 disk
sde                          8:64   0    4G  0 disk
└─vg_root-lv_data (dm-2)   253:2    0  3.5G  0 lvm  /data1
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this command in version of `iostat` where there is no -N option to list the LV's

`lvdisplay | awk '/LV Name/{blockdev=$3} /Block device/{bdid=$3; sub("[0-9]*:","dm-",bdid); print bdid,blockdev;}'`

Answer (score 1):

The correct and easiest way to do it is to use the following command:

```
iostat -Nd
```

From the man page of iostat, the option `-N` already displays the registered device mapper names.

Comment: What does this answer add over Mark Wagner's answer from 2011?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple `lvdisplay` with `awk`, like this.

```
lvdisplay | awk '/LV Name/{n=$3} /Block device/{d=$3; sub(".*:","dm-",d); print d,n;}'
```

Answer (score 0):

**Cleanest, simplest** output: `ls -lrt /dev/mapper`